# How to add image to a new window opened by a button in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The main window image is displayed but the new opened window that opens when pressing P button dosnt show the image.

Not sure why is the new window not adding the picture since I followed the same procedure as for the main window.

Note: both images are in the same directory. Thank you for the help!

```
from tkinter import *

def openWindow():
    newWindow = Toplevel(root)
    newWindow.geometry("1050x580")
    newWindow.title("P&ID")
    #newWindow.configure(background= 'grey')
    
    bg1 = PhotoImage(file = "p.png") 
    my_canvas2 = Canvas(root, width=1050, height=580, border= 0, highlightthickness=0)
    my_canvas2.pack(fill = "both", expand=True)
    
    #Set image in Cnavas
    my_canvas2.create_image(0,0, image = bg1, anchor = "nw")
    
    Label(root, text = "P")
    


root = Tk() 
root.geometry("1050x580") 
root.title(" Hellow ") 

bg = PhotoImage(file = "pht.png")

my_canvas = Canvas(root, width=1050, height=580, border= 0, highlightthickness=0)
my_canvas.pack(fill = "both", expand=True)

#Set image in Cnavas
my_canvas.create_image(0,0, image = bg, anchor = "nw")

#Add label
my_canvas.create_text(100,50, text= "T", font = ("Helvetica", 25), fill ="white")
#Add button 
button1 = Button(root, text="Saved values")
button1_window = my_canvas.create_window(780,100, anchor="sw", window = button1)
button2 = Button(root, text="Help")
button2_window = my_canvas.create_window(925, 100, anchor = "sw", window = button2)
button3 = Button(root, text="P", command= openWindow)
button3_window = my_canvas.create_window(710, 100, anchor = "sw", window = button3)

#define entry box
entry = Entry(root, font=("Helvetica", 16), width=14,fg ="dark blue", border=0)

#define the output 
output = Text(root, font=("Helvetica", 16), width=50, height= 10, fg ="dark blue", border=0)
sensor_values = Text(root, font=("Helvetica", 18), width=75, height= 1, fg ="dark blue", border=0)

#Add label for cmd box
my_canvas.create_text(150,100, text= "Enter a command:", font = ("Helvetica", 15), fill ="white")
#Add entry boxes to the canvas
cmd_window = my_canvas.create_window(70,130, anchor= "nw", window= entry)

#Add label for the output window
my_canvas.create_text(400,100, text= "Output:", font = ("Helvetica", 15), fill ="white")
out_window = my_canvas.create_window(660, 250,window = output )

mainloop()
```

Comment: Try using `my_canvas2.tk_img = bg1`. It should solve your problem (assuming it's similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34534655/11106801)).

Answer (score 1):

Use: my_canvas2.tk_img = bg1
It should be written in the new window's code

Answer (score 1):

I assume you would like my_canvas2 to be placed on the top level window hence your function should be:

```
def openWindow():
  newWindow = Toplevel(root)
  newWindow.geometry("1050x580")
  newWindow.title("P&ID")
  #newWindow.configure(background= 'grey')

  bg1 = PhotoImage(file = "p.png") 
  my_canvas2 = Canvas(newWindow,width=1050, height=580, border= 0, highlightthickness=0)
  my_canvas2.pack(fill = "both", expand=True)

  #Set image in Cnavas
  my_canvas2.create_image(0,0, image = bg1, anchor = "new")

  Label(root, text = "P")
  mainloop()
```